# like sin importar orden de palabras mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

tengo este query que hace un like a varios campos cuando lo escribo el like '%bes%tintes%' muestra correctamente los resultados, pero si busco '%tintes%bes%' no encuentra nada

```
SELECT * FROM catalogo 
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',NOMBRE,DESCRIPCION,MARCA_NOMBRE,CATEGORIA_NOMBRE,SUBCATEGORIA_NOMBRE) 
like '%bes%tintes%'
```

como puedo hacer un like que no busque de forma ordenada en el string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo logre solucionar utilizando FULLTEXT en mis columnas

1 - agregare todos mis campos como fulltext

```
ALTER TABLE catalogo ADD FULLTEXT content_filters (NOMBRE,DESCRIPCION,MARCA_NOMBRE,CATEGORIA_NOMBRE,SUBCATEGORIA_NOMBRE);
```

2 - luego hago mi consulta de la siguiente forma

```
SELECT * FROM catalogo
WHERE MATCH(NOMBRE,DESCRIPCION,MARCA_NOMBRE,CATEGORIA_NOMBRE,SUBCATEGORIA_NOMBRE) AGAINST('bess tintes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

entonces sin importar como ingrese a mi consulta el texto 'bes tintes' o 'tintes bes' o 'bessss tintes' de todas las forma encontrara un resultado

Gracias a todos por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 4):

si lo que quieres es tal cual, obtener todos los resultados que contengan `bes` y `tintes`, sin importar el orden, podrías utilizar `contains` con `near`:

```
SELECT * FROM catalogo 
WHERE CONTAINS(CONCAT_WS(' ',NOMBRE,DESCRIPCION,MARCA_NOMBRE,CATEGORIA_NOMBRE,SUBCATEGORIA_NOMBRE), 'NEAR ((bes, tintes), MAX)')
```

la función `contains` implica que, el texto base debe contener el siguiente parámetro. que en este caso es la función `NEAR`, la cual trae todos los textos ingresados en una distancia definida, que en este caso particular, pondremos `max`, porque entiendo que no hay límite alguno. en caso de que haya, reemplaza el `MAX` por la proximidad que necesites.

Comment: yo pregunto.. porque no se cuanto tarda esto en hacer el query.. y hacer like '%bes%' and like '%tintes%'?

Comment: en términos de recursos desconozco que tanto pueda utilizar, pero otra forma sencilla sería hacer el `like '%bes%' or like '%tintes%'` (or para que no importe el orden de los elementos, que es lo que especifica el usuario) que comentas

Comment: el and tampoco importa el orden.. el or, puede devolver un registro aunque no contenga uno de los valores... va and...

Comment: mala mía, haz de cuenta que no dije nada... XD

Comment: Y la respuesta mas correcta de todas (mal que me pese) seria una regexp....

Comment: L.Ronquillo tu query me retorna un "4079 - Illegal parameter data type mediumblob for operation 'st_contains' "

Answer (score 2):

Aclaro otras dos formas de hacer esto mismo.

Una es aplicando like sucesivos

```
SELECT * FROM catalogo 
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ',NOMBRE,DESCRIPCION,MARCA_NOMBRE,CATEGORIA_NOMBRE,SUBCATEGORIA_NOMBRE) 
like '%bes%'
and
CONCAT_WS(' ',NOMBRE,DESCRIPCION,MARCA_NOMBRE,CATEGORIA_NOMBRE,SUBCATEGORIA_NOMBRE) 
like '%tintes%'
```

Y otra forma mas, seria una expresion regular (de la cual no soy experto y desconozco como se haria)