# Búsqueda en datatables sin importar el orden de las palabras serverside datatables-mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, datatables

Buen día, he probado el plugin de Datatables y todo esta perfecto.
mi duda es la siguiente. Realizo la búsqueda de "juan perez" y lo encuentra, pero si busco "perez juan" no lo encuentra.

alguien tiene algún ejemplo para poder realizar ese tipo de búsquedas?

dejo este enlace como ejemplo, es lo que yo uso para mostrar los datos: https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html

En este caso encuentra "Software Engineer" pero no "Engineer Software"

Comment: Y como tienes el código de esa datatable?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [like sin importar orden de palabras mysql](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403650/like-sin-importar-orden-de-palabras-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

El tema lo tenés en que estás haciendo un:

> select * from tu_tabla where tu_columna = 'tu_palabra_busqueda'

cuando deberías hacer un:

> where tu_columna LIKE %tu_palabra_busqueda%

es decir, deberías buscar la query que genera usa tu datatable.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).